# Generic Component To make an HTTP Connection with Asyntask (ANDROID

Tags: android

I would like to know your opinion about the viability of designing a component that uses an asyntask to make custom http request, with custom I mean a kind of parameterized "query" that you build and let you make http request just by changing parameters, I hope you can give me some insights.

Answer (score 0):

Its completely "Viable" and that's what AsyncTasks are meant for.

Just build a AsyncTask and fire your query from the doInBackground() part of the Asynctask.